# How to play audio through USB device on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian

I recently got a Raspberry PI, and have been trying to play a .wav file through a connected USB speaker (which works fine on Windows 7). How do you do this in Raspbian?

Comment: This question might be better at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

would be useful to know what the speaker is.
The usb speakers is probably only powered by usb. 
Check if they have a jack input and configure your raspi-config to output audio to jack